Google OAuth Account suggestions after Sign-in breaks Authentication Flow (Blank Popup)
I've recently implemented Google Auth in our web application, and we are encountering an issue that disrupts the authentication flow for certain accounts. Here's a detailed description of the problem:
Initial Sign-In:
Users click the "Continue with Google" button, which opens a Google sign-in popup.
Google's Additional Steps:
For some accounts, after signing in, Google presents additional steps in the same popup. These steps include suggestions to add or confirm recovery information, add a home address, or set up passkeys for simplifying future sign-ins (see screenshots below).
When users click "Not now" to skip these steps, the authentication flow breaks, and our application does not proceed to log the user in. This interruption prevents the token from being returned and processed by our app.
Screenshots:
Simplify Your Sign-In Prompt
Suggestions to Complete Account Information
Flow breaks after click on "Not now"
Browser console error
Steps to Reproduce:
Click "Continue with Google" on our application.
Sign in using a Google account that triggers the additional steps.
Click "Not now" on the suggestions and passkey setup prompts.
Expected Behavior:
The application should handle these intermediate steps smoothly and still authenticate the user, returning the necessary token to our application.
The flow breaks after the user dismisses the additional steps, preventing the token from being returned and the user from being logged in.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Google OAuth and these intermediate steps? How can I ensure the authentication flow continues smoothly even when these prompts appear?
Thank you for your help!
